# Converting from twos complement to decimal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, binary, decimal-expansion

I am currently reading a textbook and I can't seem to understand what the examples in the book did. I do believe it is an error with the book, but if not can someone explain?

[image]

How come there is no negative sign in front of the final result?

Comment: Look again. There **IS** a negative sign in front of the result!

Comment: Actually there shouldn't be any negative sign: the first two rows show addition of $1$ and $1$, and under the line they say $-10_2$ and $-2_{10}$. Why no sign — because inversion and increment is equivalent to negating a twos-complement binary number, and negating $-2$ must give you $+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-2_{ten}=\begin {cases}-000000...000010_{two} \ \  \text{in signed binary}\\
 \ \ \ 11111111...1110_{two} \ \  \text {in 2's complement binary}\\
\end{cases}$

In $2$'s complement binary the sign is expressed by the leading $1$'s.

Taking the absolute value of a negative number (leading $1$'s) in $2$'s complement binary is flipping the bits and then adding one.